# RelativeLayout isn't centred in its LinearLayout parent

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have tried to centre an RelativeLayout in its LinearLayout parent.

But it keeps staying to the left.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Btw, only one of the two is visible at a current time: (refresh/action linearLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/app_widget_root"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="0dp"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_main"
              >
              <!--   -->
             <RelativeLayout 
              android:id="@+id/layout_main"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"  
              android:gravity="center_vertical"           
              >

                        <!--========================================================================
                            * Action layout - action buttons container
                            ======================================================================== -->
                        <LinearLayout 
                        android:id="@+id/layout_action"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_information"
                        >
                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_action"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_drive_disabled"
                         android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        />
                        <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/text_view_action"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:textSize="15sp"
                         android:textStyle="bold"       
                         android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                         android:textColor="@color/disabled_white"                       
                         android:text="Drive!"                
                        />
                        </LinearLayout> <!-- Action layout -->
                    <!--========================================================================
                        * Refresh layout - refresh layout
                        ======================================================================== -->              
                        <RelativeLayout 
                              android:id="@+id/layout_refresh"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="110dp"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                              android:visibility="invisible"      
                              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                              >
                              <!-- 
                              android:clickable="true"
                              android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" -->
                              <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_refresh"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_refresh_idle"
                              android:layout_gravity="center"
                             />

                              <TextView android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:textSize="18sp"
                              android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                              android:textColor="@color/solid_white"                         
                              android:text="Click to refresh"                
                              />
                      </RelativeLayout> <!--  refresh notification view -->
              </RelativeLayout> <!--  main view -->             
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE1**

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
<RelativeLayout 
                              android:id="@+id/layout_refresh"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="110dp"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:visibility="invisible"      
                              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_status_image"    
                              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                              android:gravity="center"
                              android:layout_gravity="center"
                              >
                              <!-- 
                              android:clickable="true"
                              android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" -->
                              <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_refresh"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_refresh_idle"
                              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                              />

                              <TextView android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:textSize="18sp"
                              android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                              android:textColor="@color/solid_white"                         
                              android:text="Click to refresh"                
                              />
```

[image]

I want to make the image and text in the center

**Update 3**

XML

```
android:id="@+id/app_widget_root"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_main"

android:clickable="true"

android:focusable="true"

android:orientation="horizontal"

android:padding="0dp" 

android:gravity="center_vertical"

>



   <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/layout_status_image"

        android:layout_width="82dp"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        android:layout_weight=".2">





        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/image_status"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"

            android:src="@drawable/widget_icon_no_data"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <!--

                          Layout is necessary because the setVisibility of ProgressBar is not working 

  through remote views in 2.1. So wrapped by this layout 

        -->



        <FrameLayout

            android:id="@+android:id/widget_progress"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" 

            android:layout_centerInParent="true">



            <ProgressBar

                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"

                android:layout_width="39dp"

                android:layout_height="39dp"

                android:indeterminateOnly="true"

                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout> <!-- Status image layout -->





    <!--

                        ========================================================================

* Information layout - contains all the texts 

========================================================================

    -->



    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/layout_information"

        android:layout_width="190dp"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" 

        android:layout_weight=".6"

        >



        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/text_view_destination"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"



            android:paddingTop="8dp"

            android:text="\@ Home in"

            android:textColor="@color/solid_white"

            android:textSize="19sp"

            android:textStyle="bold" />



        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/text_view_time"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            android:paddingLeft="9dp"

            android:textColor="@color/solid_white"

            android:textSize="25sp"

            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout> <!-- Information layout -->

    <!--

                        ========================================================================

* Action layout - action buttons container

========================================================================

    -->



    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/layout_action"

        android:layout_width="80dp"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:gravity="center"

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_weight=".2"

        >



        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/image_action"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_contenth"

            android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_drive_disabled" />



        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/h"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"

            android:text="Refresh"

            android:textColor="@color/disabled_white"

            android:textSize="15sp"

            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout> <!-- Action layout -->
```

Screen:

[image]

I have removed the relativeLayout, but yet the `Refresh Text`
isn't centered in its box.

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you referring to `android:id="@+id/image_action"`? If so, have you tried `android:layout_greavity="center"`?

Comment: relating to `android:id="@+id/layout_refresh"`

Comment: Try using `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in your `ImageView` `android:id="@+id/image_refresh"`

Comment: You should read a bit about the `layout_gravity` and `gravity` attributes, half of those attributes are useless in your layout.

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/app_widget_root"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"

Change layout_width for your linear layout to match_parent

Comment: i have tried your xml,but can't get idea.@Elad Benda can you please add snap what is your desired output.

Comment: @mipreamble what will this do? match_parent at the top-leve linearLayout? who is its parent? the screen?

Comment: @EladBenda: Their was too much wrong in the code. Posted a new answer check it out. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

1 - In linearlayout : use gravity / layoutgravity / weight

2 - In Relaive layout : use layout_centerInParent/ layout_alignParent... / layout_toRightOf-layout_toLeftOf

Comment: You shouldn't use orientation and gravity/layout-gravity in relativelayout

Comment: isn't your relativelayout at the right why use "android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_status_image" " ?

Answer (score 1):

You have it all wrong. Try this

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_refresh"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_refresh_idle"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"  -dont use gravity, use centerInParent-
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18sp"
                            NOTICE THESE TWO LINES HERE
android:layout_centerHorizontal="" -dont use margins, use centerHorizontal-
android:layout_below="@id/image_refresh" -use below imagerefresh, this should work-
                            END
android:textColor="@color/solid_white"                         
android:text="Click to refresh"                
/>
```

**Fundamentals**

LinearLayout understands layout_gravity and layout_weights. RelativeLayout does not understand layout_gravity.

**android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_status_image"** in your RelativeLayout is correct. It positions the Refresh layout to the left of your layout **layout_status_image**.

Comment: `dont use gravity, use centerInParent-` but I haven't. Anyway copy pasting your xml got me back to the left alignment. Not good

Comment: Look carefully. It has a `android:layout_gravity="center"` on your image_refresh. As you read the answer carefully you will also notice recommendations on `refresh_text`. To make the answer more useful to others when they visit it, it is a good idea to make it clear to readers what the issue was, so that they dont have to go through tons of lines of code to get it. As you spend more time on SO you will begin to realize the difference between good complete answers and just answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_refresh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
        <!-- 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" -->

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"                         
            android:text="Click to refresh"                
        />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout> <!--  refresh notification view -->
```

In this you need to change image src because i don't have this image which you use therefore i use iclauncher image here...

And now its perfectly comes center in any size of your layout.

You use Visible and Invisible as per your requirement.

Comment: what did you change from my xml?

Comment: I use LinearLayout inside Relative layout and put center_horizontal property.

Answer (score 0):

Too many Layout in the code.

Relative layout is not needed anywhere.

Please edit the images in the imageview as required. If this does not solve your issue. Please post what you want to do exactly with the images and text. Will send you the fixed code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/app_widget_root"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:baselineAligned="false">


    <!--========================================================================
        * Action layout - action buttons container
        ======================================================================== -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_action"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="5">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Drive!"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Action layout -->
    <!--========================================================================
        * Refresh layout - refresh layout
        ======================================================================== -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_refresh"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="5">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Refresh"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does `android:layout_width="match_parent"` means when it comes at the top=most layout?

Comment: `Relative layout is not needed anywhere` thumb-rule: when is RelativeLayout needed?

Comment: @EladBenda: U need Relative Layout when you have multiple items which needs to be displayed below above before or after any specific view.

So does the solution work?